# For loop and if statement within a method

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, math, methods

I am new to using java and am having some issues in my java class right now and will be needing help with my specific code. I try to look at others questions on here all the time but it's never exactly what I need. Here are my directions:

Create a Java file called `CompoundInterestYourLastName`.  Write a method called `computeBalance()` that computes the balance of a bank account with a given initial balance and interest rate, after a given number of years. Assume interest is compounded yearly.

Use a loop to control the iterations through the years in your method.

Your method should return a double value.

In your main method, run the following tests to verify your method is working correctly.

```
System.out.printf("Your total is $%.2f", computeBalance(1000, .045, 3));
// should return $1141.17
```

I am using eclipse and my only current error is in the comments. I also want some general tips and let me know if my logic is wrong. It probably is. :D

Here is what I have currently although I have been trying different things:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class CompoundInterestTidwell {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double compInt = computeBalance(1000, 0.045, 3);
        System.out.printf("Your new balance is $%.2f", compInt);
    }

    // Getting arror for line of code below. 
    // Error: This method must return a result of type double
    public static double computeBalance(int P, double r, int t) {
        // Formula for compounding interest
        // A = P(1+(r/n))^(n(t))
        // The examples to check my math had rate already divided by 100 so I left out r/n.

        for(int c = 0; c <= t; c++ ) {
            // deleted 'n' from equation because it need to equal 1 anyways.
            double compInt = Math.pow(P*(1+r), t);

            if (c < t) {
                c++;
                return compInt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `computeBalance` doesn't guarantee to return a value, because the only return statement is in an `if` clause, within a loop (making it two conditions deep).

This is a thing the compiler is warning you about. Basically it scans your code and makes sure that a function declared as `double` will actually return a valid value of type `double` and so on.

If you add a return statement at the end of the body in the function (or throw an error) it should compile.

I am not exactly sure what your function does in technical terms, but I've rewritten it so it should return the same value, but should now actually compile.

```
public static double computeBalance(int P, double r, int t) {
    // Formula for compounding interest
    // A = P(1+(r/n))^(n(t))
    // The examples to check my math had rate already divided by 100 so I left out r/n.

    double compInt = 0; // Declare compInt outside the loop.

    for(int c = 0; c <= t; c++ ) {
        // deleted 'n' from equation because it need to equal 1 anyways.
        compInt = Math.pow(P*(1+r), t);

        if (c < t) {
            c++;
            break; // Break instead of return, will immediately 
                   // go to the return statement outside the loop.
        }
    }

    return compInt; // Moved the return statement to outside the loop so 
                    // the function always will return a double.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually had it here before: 


if (c < t) {
   c++;
   
  }
  
  return compInt;

This way it is still inside my for-loop but outside my if-statement. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Tori If it's inside your loop it will still not be guaranteed to return. Because the second argument in a for loop is also an `if` condition, it's entirely possible to not even enter the for loop. You must have a return statement outside the loop that your function will be guaranteed to reach for your error to go away.

Comment: @Tori I've added some example code of the function `computeBalance` where I've fixed the problems I described.